# How do you return the market cap of an ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, explorer-api, api

After an ICO, a token contract has essentially converted ethers into a token through the minting process.

Once this token’s initial supply has been minted, how do you call the blockchain to return the market cap of that token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Market cap = price of currency * circulating supply***

So, as an example, the market capitalization at the time of writing of Tezos is 1,550,977,120 euros:

€2.19 (unit price of an XTZ token) * 708,208,731 XTZ (number of Tezos in circulation)

**1st** : **Get Circulating Supply** in web3 from a LPtokens(PairAddress)

**Step1** :  Import Factory Function :

```
const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
  "AddFactoryHere", //Add here
  [
  'event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1,address pair, uint)',
  'function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair)',
  'function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint)',
  'function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast)'
  ],
  signer // Add your here
);
```

**Step2** : What Pair ? Example :

```
const TokenA = 'AddressHere' 
const TokenB = 'AddressHere'
```

**Step3** : Call function **GetPair** to get answer of **PairAddress** :

```
const pairAddress = await factoryContract.getPair(TokenA,TokenB);
```

**Step4** : Call function **getReserves** to get reserves tokens:

**Be carreful sometime result of reserve inverse token !!! You need fix it**

```
const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, abi, provider); //Import ABI , build provider etc ...
const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves();
```

Here you get 2 answer : **reserves[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221666/get-the-price-of-tokens-with-web3js)** and **reserves[0]**;

And you need get **DECIMAL** of each token to make good convertion

```
const tokenContracttoken = new web3.eth.Contract(abiOfToken,"AddressOfToken"); //import AbiOfStandardToken
const decimalstoken = await tokenContracttoken.methods.decimals().call();
```

***Here you have number of Token from a PairAddress .***

What to do for get **price** is just call function **getAmountsOut** from **router** with value of **1** to get the current Price of Token do same step as up ..
Full method to do is here : [Clic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221666/get-the-price-of-tokens-with-web3js)

**Note** :
If you think its hard to do your wrong, its pretty simple its like ask question to someone and get answer like : Hello how are you ? I'm good
Its the same for web3.js you call answer like What is Reserve of (WBNB-BUSD) with function provided of smart contract **getReserves** and you get answer
MarketCap is different for eachDex and LiquidityPool if i'm allright

Is that good for you ?

Comment: Could you give code examples?

Comment: Add question anything you want we are here to help you

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but feel that a warning must be added: do not rely on a pool's spot price for important calculations. It's easy to manipulate. Use oracle prices instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by "market cap"?

From [Coinbase Learn](https://www.coinbase.com/es/learn/crypto-basics/what-is-market-cap):

> For a cryptocurrency like Bitcoin, market capitalization (or market
> cap) is the total value of all the coins that have been mined. It’s
> calculated by multiplying the number of coins in circulation by the
> current market price of a single coin.

So, market cap is the value (usually in dollars) of all your tokens.

If you want to know how many tokens have been minted, you must call the [function totalSupply](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-totalSupply--) from your token Smart Contract.

Comment: I know what the market cap is. My question is **how do you find the market cap of a token** , perhaps using an API or something